# hide duplicate div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, hide

I have some layers that are dynamically put in as follows

```
<div><p class="locid">2<p></div>
<div><p class="locid">1<p></div>
<div><p class="locid">2<p></div>
<div><p class="locid">3<p></div>
<div><p class="locid">4<p></div>
```

What I need to do is hide the second occurrence of this layer so it appears as follows

```
<div><p class="locid">2<p></div>
<div><p class="locid">1<p></div>
<div><p class="locid">3<p></div>
<div><p class="locid">4<p></div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get a collection of p's matching some value
$("p.locid").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == '2';

// hide the (div) parent of the second match
}).eq(1).parent().hide();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WjgxQ/

Comment: This one only works if the content is literally "2". I don't think it's what the question is about.

Comment: My understanding is along the lines of: 'given some value, I want to hide the div which matches the second occurrence of that value'.

Comment: Same. In that case I don't understand your script :P

Comment: @Litso - I've thrown in comments, in case it helps.

Comment: This works if I only have one duplicate on the page but if I have more than one duplicate it only hides the first duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

This does exactly what you're looking for ;)

Comment: That's not actually what `jQuery.unique()` does. It only removes duplicates if they are the same actual element. So if you have two elements that have the same content, class, etc., so they appear to be identical, they are actually considered to be two unique elements because they are not the same element. They just look the same. As such, `jQuery.unique()` would not remove either one. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Try this.

```
var a = new Array();
$('p.locid').each(function(){
    text = $(this).text();
    if($.inArray(text, a)){
        $(this).closest('div').hide();
    }else{
        a.push(text);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = new array();

$('.locid').each(function(){
  if ($.inArray($(this).text(), arr) !== -1){
     $(this).closest('div').remove();
  }
  else{
    arr[] = $(this).text();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var a = new Array();

$('p').each(function(index) {
    text = $(this).text();
    if($.inArray(text, a)!=-1){
        $(this).closest('p').hide();
    }else{
        a.push(text);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WjgxQ/59/